# PHP Encode string as HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, html-encode

I have this code below, which comes from Wordpress Core file /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php

```
  printf(
    '<a class="row-title" href="%s" aria-label="%s">%s%s</a>',
    get_edit_post_link( $post->ID ),
    /* translators: %s: post title */
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( '&#8220;%s&#8221; (Edit)' ), $title )),
    $pad,
    $title
  );
```

In my case the variable $title contains iconfont HTML i.e.

```
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
```

[image]

The PHP code is making the web browser display the HTML characters as a string rather than what I'm after which is to display as HTML and render the Font Awesome Icon.

Ive tried wrapping $title in

```
htmlentities()
html_entity_decode()
htmlspecialchars()
```

Can some one help thanx

Comment: have you tried with ? `htmlentities($title, ENT_HTML5);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you use html_entity_decode? I've tried this:

```
printf(
    '<a class="row-title" href="%s" aria-label="%s">%s%s</a>',
    get_edit_post_link( $post->ID ),
    /* translators: %s: post title */
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( '&#8220;%s&#8221; (Edit)' ), $title )),
    $pad,
    html_entity_decode($title)
  );
```

and seems it works.

But this is BAD idea to change core file. You can try to write (or find) some plugin that allows to add icons to particular post title but not to all post and without changing original file.

Comment: Yes this works thanx, I had overlooked this on my first attempt as nothing had displayed but then I realised that the Font Awesome css file was not included on the Admin side